# why is it not good to stall a cold engine

Tags: engine, temperature

I've always known that you cannot stall (regular turn off by turning key (i'm not sure how that's called in english)) an engine if it is not yet reached it's work temperature. For example, if i go to a store and it's close enough for the car to not be able to warm up, i would take a slightly longer route so that the engine can warm up to working temperature. That's kind of been ingrained in me by my father. But i do not know why.

So the question is --

**what damage (if any) is caused by not allowing the car to warm up before stalling it?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You won't damage a vehicle by shutting it off before it gets to full operating temperature. This, in some places, could be considered a waste of gas. There are two things you need to be aware of though. If you are continually doing this on a regular basis, you will cause condensation in the crank case. This excess moisture can contaminate the oil and possibly cause corrosion on your bearing surfaces and otherwise cause sludge buildup in your engine. The second thing to consider is, your battery needs time to recharge. Continual short trips may cause degradation of your battery over time, causing it a shorter than expected life.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. Although for me as a car lover (and a lover of my car in particular) any time spent over the time that's actually necessary is enjoyed. To quote mister Lennon -- "Time you enjoy wasting is not wasted time."

Comment: Very nice quote. I'm assuming that is from John and not that dude who spells it *Lenin* :D I agree with you to enjoy your car is a great thing. Many times just driving your car brings that enjoyment.